# Normal order sequencing vs applicative order sequencing

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to understand [this](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/spring11/proglang/handouts/lambda-calculus-chapter.pdf) lecture, section 2.7. Why would the normal order sequencing print out `"hello" "world"` and not `"world" "hello"`? I may be misinterpreting the order in which the arguments are applied.

It looks like the expression

$$
((Seq (display "hello"))\; (display "world"))
$$

would evaluate to

$$
\lambda z.((display "world")\; (display "hello"))
$$

and that would, under normal order, would print out `"world" "hello"`.

My question is whether the assumption I'm making is correct. If not, could you show the correct derivation of the end-expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're misreading the combinator. In these lecture notes, lambda abstraction binds tighter than application (the opposite convention is more common — it's apparent from the spacing but the author should state that explicitly). I'll use extra (redundant) parentheses in my answers to avoid any potential for ambiguity. The combinator is
$$ \mathit{Seq} = \lambda x. \lambda y. ((\lambda z.y) \: x)$$
So
$$ \begin{align}
  & ((\mathit{Seq} \; (\text{display "hello"})) \; (\text{display "world"})) \\
  &\qquad = (((\lambda x. \lambda y. ((\lambda z.y) \; x)) \; (\text{display "hello"})) \; (\text{display "world"})) \\
  &\qquad \to^2 ((\lambda z. (\text{display "world"})) \; (\text{display "hello"})) \\
  &\qquad \xrightarrow{\text{display "hello"}} (\text{display "world"}) \\
  &\qquad \xrightarrow{\text{display "world"}} \mathord{?} \\
\end{align} $$
where $M \xrightarrow{\text{action}} N$ means that $M$ evaluates to $N$ performing the specified action.

Comment: I think this [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56449/normal-order-sequencing-combinator-why-does-it-work) reveals that `Seq` doesn't work as it should.

Comment: @AntonTrunov It works but the semantics is bizarre, since `display` is basically evaluated in applicative order. And I don't see that specified in the lecture notes.

Comment: Then why "hello" doesn't get printed after the first $\beta$-reduction? (when we substitute (display "hello") for $x$)).

Comment: A quote from the notes: "This combinator guarantees that $x$ is evaluated before $y$, which is important
in programs with side-effects." I understand it as -- Seq is a "universal" combinator, so it should work not only for display (it's for the case when we make (display ...) a special form).