# Normal order sequencing combinator - why does it work?

Tags: lambda-calculus

[Notes on lambda calculus](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/spring11/proglang/handouts/lambda-calculus-chapter.pdf#10) (part 2.7) and book Programming Distributed Computing Systems: A Foundational Approach by Varela present the sequencing combinator for normal order reduction:

$$\mathit{Seq} = \lambda x. \lambda y. ((\lambda z.y) \: x)$$

In the following example

$$((\mathit{Seq} \; (\text{display "hello"})) \; (\text{display "world"}))$$

it should guarantee that $(\text{display "hello"})$ is evaluated before $(\text{display "world"})$. But I don't understand why is $(\text{display "hello"})$ evaluated at all — why it isn't simply thrown away when evaluating

$$(\lambda z. (\text{display "world"})) \; (\text{display "hello"})$$

My reasoning: $z$ doesn't have free occurence in $(\text{display "world"})$ so substituting $(\text{display "hello"})$ for $z$ in $(\text{display "world"})$ results simply in $(\text{display "world"})$.

My question is related to [Normal order sequencing vs applicative order sequencing](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19507/normal-order-sequencing-vs-applicative-order-sequencing).

Comment: It's just wrong. Your reasoning is correct even with their definitions. There's a reason `seq` is primitive in Haskell; it's not implementable as a lambda term. There are other things weird about this. It warns that "$z$ should not be free in $y$" but that makes no sense. $y$ is a bound variable. The only way $z$ could be free in $y$ is if $z = y$, but then why not worry about $y$ being free in $x$? If you want, you can make `display` in Haskell using `unsafePerformIO` and demonstrate that `display "Hello"` will not be evaluated.

Comment: It can be made to work, but it requires complicated definitions that aren't in that document. Your reasoning is correct for a “reasonable” definition of the semantics of $(\mathrm{display} \: s)$.

Comment: @Gilles: could you be more specific as to what would be necessary for it to work?

Comment: I tend to agree with the OP: the following Haskell program, `se = \x -> \y -> ((\z -> y) x)` followed by `(se (putStrLn "hello") (putStrLn "world"))` only prints "`world`"

Comment: @Jay That is not a good example. It doesn't tell you whether `putStrLn "hello"` has been *evaluated* or not, only that it hasn't been executed. `seq (putStrLn "hello") (putStrLn "world")` will *also* not print "hello". (Technically, Haskell's evaluation is "non-strict" which gives it a lot of leeway in implementation, for example, it allows speculative evaluation. It wouldn't be incorrect for a Haskell implementation to evaluate `display "Hello"` as in my previous comment. In practice, they don't, which is also a correct implementation of non-strictness.)

Comment: @DerekElkins Right, I haven't programmed in Haskell for some time, forgot about that.